# numpy.linspace get IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, numpy

While using numpy.linespace in a for loop i got this error: IndexError: list index out of range. This happen only if the number of samples for the numpy.linspace function is greater then the number of loops.
The code is:

```
def interp(x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1, t0, t1, n):
x = numpy.linspace(x0, x1, n)
y = numpy.linspace(y0, y1, n)
z = numpy.linspace(z0, z1, n)
t = numpy.linspace(t0, t1, n)

return x, y, z, t

def interpolation(x, y, z, t, n):
size = len(x)
x_app = []
y_app = []
z_app = []
t_app = []

for i in range(size - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, size):
        x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1, t0, t1= x[i], x[j], y[i], y[j], z[i], z[j], t[i], t[j]
        x_int, y_int, z_int, t_int= interp(x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1, t0, t1, n)
        for i in range(n):
            x_app.append(x_int[i])
            y_app.append(y_int[i])
            z_app.append(z_int[i])
            t_app.append(t_int[i])

return x_app, y_app, z_app, t_app
```

The complete error report:

```
File "C:\Users\salci\Desktop\Tirocinio\heatMap\heatMapLibrary.py", line 132, in interpolation
    x0, x1, y0, y1, z0, z1, t0, t1= x[i], x[j], y[i], y[j], z[i], z[j], t[i], t[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Notes: x, y, z, t are list of 16 elements. So this error happens for n>16.

Comment: One or more of your indices is out of range. Print the values of the indices and the lengths of your lists to find out which one, and then take it from there.

Comment: One of `x`, `y`, `z`, or `t` isn't as long as you're expecting, probably.

Comment: The error occurs before the call to `interp`, and hence before any of the `linspace` calls.  So your title is wrong!  The error is in one (or more) `x[i]`, x[j]` etc.  Since `x,y,z,t` (and `n`) are arguments to this function and you don't define or describe any of them, we can't help you.

Comment: Correct the function indents!